# bash : to keep all values > 3500 with sed

Tags: bash

I 've a question concerning sed cmd: how to keep all values > 3500 in a field?

this is my problem: 
I've as output (from a .csv file):

```
String1;Val1;String2;Val2
```

i would like to keep all lines where Val1 is only > 3500 and Val2 >= 60,00 (<= 99,99)

so, i tried this:

```
`sed -nr 's/^(.*);
([^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-2][0-9]{3}|3[0-4][0-9]{2}|3500)]);
(.*);
([6-9][0-9],[0-9]*)$
/Dans la ville de \1, \2 votants avec un pourcentage de \4 pour \3/p'
`
```

but i 've this error:

```
`sed -e expression #1, char 174: Unmatched ) or \)`
```

i think the problem come from the search of the second field.
i look all numbers <= 3500 and i put NOT(these tests).

Do u have an idea to how should i proceed? 
Thanks.

(and sry for this terrible english)

Comment: Don't use `sed` for this; use `awk`.

Comment: I might be wrong, but IMHO, `[a-exyz]` and `[^a-exyz]` are pure character classes, not containing other expressions, except ranges like a-e. so the `([` inside of such a class is taken literally. I'm surprised, that not a ] inside of it is warned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing error is in `[^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-2][0-9]{3}|3[0-4]`. I'm not entirely sure where exactly, but that doesn't matter since there is an error in your approach:

(Inverted) character classes `[^...]` do *not* work on full strings. `[^ab|xy]` matches all *single* characters that are not `a`, `b`, `|`, `x`, or `y`. 
If you want to say *»all strings except 0, 1, 2, ..., 3500«* you have to use something different, probably a positive formulation like *»all strings from 3500, 3501, ...«*.

The following regex should work for numbers >= 3500.

```
0*([1-9][0-9]{4,}|[4-9][0-9]{3}|3[5-9][0-9]{2})
```

Comment: thank you, i finally do that : `sed -rn 's/^(.*);(350[1-9]|35[1-9][0-9]|3[6-9][0-9]{2}|[4-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4,});(.*);([6-9][0-9],[0-9]*)$/Dans la ville de \1, \2 votants avec un pourcentage de \4 pour \3/p' ` and it's working

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** is the right way to go in such case:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=";" }$2 > 3500 && ($4 >= 60.00 && $4 <= 99.99)' file
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i have to use sed only (yes i know it's not the best but ... :s )